# Passing object to a function and accessing its properties [C++ & OpenGL)

Tags: c++, oop

I was using the typedef struct method to declare a parent and its properties. However, when I pass an instance of the object to another function and access its properties, I am getting "0" for the variables(print out from DrawDisc) despite assigning values to them in the last function.

However, when I print out the pos properties in the MyMouse function after assigning values to pos[0] and pos[1], I get the correct values.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct discType
{
    double pos[2];          // The X and Y coordinates of the center of the disc.
    double speed[2];        // The velocity of the disc in X and Y directions. Can be negative.
    double radius;          // Radius of the disc.
    unsigned char color[3]; // R, G, B colors of the disc.
} discType;


int numDiscs = 0;                   // Number of discs that have been added.

discType disc[ MAX_NUM_OF_DISCS ];  // Array for storing discs.

bool drawWireframe = false;         // Draw polygons in wireframe if true, otherwise
                                    // otherwise polygons are filled.

int winWidth = 800;                 // Window width in pixels.
int winHeight = 600;                // Window height in pixels.

void DrawDisc(const discType *d)
{
    static bool firstTime = true;
    static double unitDiscVertex[ NUM_OF_SIDES + 1 ][2];

    if ( firstTime )
    {
        firstTime = false;
    }
   
    cout << d->pos[0] << endl;   //prints '0'
    cout << d->pos[1] << endl;   //prints '0'

}

void MyMouse(int btn, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if ( btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN )
    {
        if ( numDiscs >= MAX_NUM_OF_DISCS )
            printf( "Already reached maximum number of discs.\n" );
        else
        {
            discType d;

            d.pos[0] = (double)x;
            d.pos[1] = (double)y;
            
            // For testing
            cout<<d.pos[0]<<endl;
            cout<<d.pos[1]<<endl;

            DrawDisc(&d);

            numDiscs++;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: Step through the code under your debugger.  Q: What compiler are you using?  What debugger is available to you?  Are you familiar with how to use it?

Comment: Your example has a lot of things that aren't used which make me think you have tried to simplify things for your question but that simplification doesn't demonstrate the problem anymore. If I strip your example down to the bare bones you can see it works: https://ideone.com/E17qt7 I suspect you have an issue with variable lifetime where the local variable goes out of scope leaving whatever uses it later with a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have an array of disks:

```cpp
discType disc[ MAX_NUM_OF_DISCS ];
```

Here we have a method that initialises an entirely unrelated disk:

```cpp
void MyMouse(int btn, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if ( btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN )
    {
        if ( numDiscs >= MAX_NUM_OF_DISCS )
            printf( "Already reached maximum number of discs.\n" );
        else
        {
            discType d; //< I am unrelated!

            /* snip */
    
            DrawDisc(&d);

            numDiscs++; //< I somehow relate to the global array?
        }
    }
}
```

Did you intend to do:

```cpp
void MyMouse(int btn, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if ( btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN )
    {
        if ( numDiscs >= MAX_NUM_OF_DISCS )
            printf( "Already reached maximum number of discs.\n" );
        else
        {
            disc[numDiscs].pos[0] = (double)x;
            disc[numDiscs].pos[1] = (double)y;
            
            // For testing
            cout<<disc[numDiscs].pos[0]<<endl;
            cout<<disc[numDiscs].pos[1]<<endl;

            DrawDisc(&disc[numDiscs]);

            numDiscs++;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
    }
}
```